# Specify multiple permissions with android:permission on activity

Tags: android

In my android application, I have an activity which specifies an intent filter. So, I want to protect it by specifying the android:permission attribute. I want to specify following four permissions:

- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.READ_LOGS

But it seems, android:permission allows only one permission. How can I achieve this? I want the caller to have all these permissions before launching my activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to define more than one permission to activity.
You can check other permission by you can use [checkCallingPermission()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingPermission%28java.lang.String%29)  method

Answer (score 3):

You use multiple uses-permissions tags, as in this:

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

    <application>
        .
        .
        .
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `android:permission` attribute on an `<activity>` tag isn't used for ensuring that other applications have the necessary permission for your Activity to run properly.

The permission attribute is used to restrict which application can launch your Activity. For example, you might define a custom `com.example.yourapp.DO_SOMETHING` permission that any other application must request from you in order to launch your app.

If your Activity needs those four permissions to run, then your application must still be the one requesting those permissions with `<uses-permission>` tags. Another application cannot request those permissions and then transitively grant them to your Activity.